# what's difference between AdaptedLeskTanimoto and AdaptedLesk

Tags: nlp, similarity, wordnet

What's difference between AdaptedLeskTanimoto and AdaptedLesk in wordnet similarity?

in JWS :

- AdaptedLesk
- AdaptedLeskTanimoto
- AdaptedLeskTanimotoNoHyponyms

Answer (score 1):

From the book "[Advances in Artificial Intelligence: 9th Mexican International Conference on Artificial Intelligence, MICAI 2010, Pachuca, Mexico, November 2010 - part I](http://books.google.it/books?id=WLObFVh1LewC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false)":

" *[...] The **Adapted Lesk Tanimoto** is a modification of **Adapted Lesk** measure, which gets the glosses of all synsets that have a direct WordNet relation with each of the input senses, and then get the hyponyms of a hypernym of a sense. Then, the Jaccard-Tanimoto Coefficient is calculated over two vectors containing the count of each word found in all the words in the gloss.
The **Adapted Lesk Tanimoto No Hyponyms**, is similar that before measure but in this case, we do not get the hyponyms of the hypernyms relations of a given synset. [...]*"

The text that I've reported here is also featured as a free preview on the link given (on Google Books), so you can also find it by yourself and read the whole paragraph in which it's contained.

You can find a basic explanation on the *Jaccard-Tanimoto Coefficient* - which characterizes Adapted Lesk Tanimoto - [here](http://mines.humanoriented.com/classes/2010/fall/csci568/portfolio_exports/sphilip/tani.html).

Hope this helps.